# Calculate:How many students?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

Each of the students was in the theater exactly twice, having watched performances $A$, $B$ or $C$. At the same time, performances $A$, $B$, $C$ were seen by $25$, $12$ and $23$ students, respectively.  How many students are there in the class?
need to solve using the Euler-Venn diagrams

Comment: The sum of the students in each performance must be twice the number of students.  Even if you want to use other methods, at least this will tell you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image] Here is the Venn Diagram BTW

Number of students in the class is just $(25+12+23)/2 = 30$, each student having watched $2$ performances so we divide by $2.$

Comment: yes, but how to depict it on the Euler-Vienna diagrams?

Comment: I have added a Venn Diagram. There are no students who only go to performance A, or only B, or only C, or all three, so I have drawn $0$ there. Sorry that its a little sloppy. I'm on a laptop so I was using a mouse.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!